# Printing a Priority Queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am attempting to print a STL priority_queue in C++, but I am having issues printing all elements of the queue.

```
priority_queue<Job, vector<Job>, greater<Job>> q = pq;
for(int i = 0; i <= q.size(); i++) {
    cout << q.top() << "\n";
    q.pop();
}
```

However, using this code when there is one or two elements in the list it is fine, but as soon as I enter three or more elements it cuts off the last item to be printed. I'm not really sure why this is happening but it's been confusing me for a little while.

Comment: Ask yourself what will happen in your loop if the size of the queue is 0 and `i <= q.size()` is evaluated.

Comment: `for (int i=0;i <= q.size(); i++)` is a total of `size() + 1` iteratons and  then you are changing the size in the loop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For loops arent really meant to be used for cases when the condition is "dynamic". What I mean is: `i <= q.size()` is of course evaluated on every iteration, but `q.size()` is also changing on each iteration. It is not impossible to get the for loop right, but a `while` is more natural:

```
while (! q.empty() ) {
    cout << q.top() << "\n";
    q.pop();
}
```

Your code is wrong because you increment `i` on every iteraton and at the same time `q.size()` decreases on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

since you are changing the size of priority queue in the loop, the code is not running correct. Try following code :

```
priority_queue<Job, vector<Job>, greater<Job>> q = pq;
size_t size = pq.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    cout << q.top() << "\n";
    q.pop();
}
```

Comment: A `while()` loop better conveys the intent here.